# How would you compensate speed on an animation with different offset?

Tags: jquery, animation, math

This is my code:

```
$('.element').click(function () {
    var offsetTop = $('.destination').offset().top;
    $('html,body').stop(true, false).animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop }, 800);
});
```

And I trigger this code on different (vertical) place of my webpage.
Since the offset change, the speed to the destination is different (the more I click on top, the faster the animation is).

How would you compensate this animation? Having the same speed on every vertical/offset value?

Here there's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/o2oq4y38/1/

Click on 1, and take care of the scrolling speed. Than click on 8, and see how slower it is.

Comment: apply this animation on click and stop the previous animation

Comment: Without an example it's tricky to understand exactly what you mean. If I do get what you mean, then, because speed is a product of distance and time, you need to either reduce the distance or increase the animation time.

Comment: Ok, example is coming....

Comment: Added an example, check the bottom of the question ;)

Comment: I know speed is product of distance and time, but they are not growing in a linear way. So if time is 800 and offset are 400 and 8000, the speed are not linear using 400*800 and 8000*800...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate `speed` of animation dynamically according to the `offset`.

```
$('.element').click(function () {
    var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top,
        destinationTop = $('.destination').offset().top,
        speed = ((destinationTop - offsetTop) / $(window).height()) * 800;
        // Speed calculation according to the distance to cover

    $('html,body').stop(true, false).animate({
        scrollTop: destinationTop
    }, speed);

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o2oq4y38/2/

This will scroll to top with same speed from anywhere on the page.

Comment: Not sure if you got what I mean. Check the example I've posted. In your case, speed is always the same value, which should change I guess...